# More pythonic way of updating an existing value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets assume I got a dictionary `_dict` and a variable `n`.

```
_dict = {'a': 9, 'b': 7, 'c': 'someValue'}
n = 8
```

I want to update just a single entry e.g. `{'b': 7}` only if the value of `n` is greater than the actual value of `b`.
The solution I got so far is

```
_dict.update({'b': n for key, value in _dict.items() if key == 'b' and n > value})
```

Which provides the desired result of `{'a': 9, 'b': 8, 'c': 'someValue'}`. So now to my question: Is there a shorter, more pythonic way of doing this? (preferably without importing additional modules)

Comment: Why do you have to create a new dictionary? You can simply write this with an `if` condition.

Comment: Why are you looping for **one** key? You can simply access it directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters @thefortheye I previously tried to update the single value conditionally with an `if` clause and that didnt worked out so it escalated quickly to looping through the dictionary.. (which is in my case no performance problem cause the dictionary has just 5-10 keys). But thanks for your advices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no point in looping if you just need to update one key:

```
_dict['b'] = max(_dict['b'], n)
```

The above sets `'b'` to the highest value of the two.

Comment: This is way too simple for my brain, but exactly what I am looking for. Retrospectively my question looks quite dumb. Thanks @Martijn Pieters!

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as that

```
if n > _dict['b']:
    _dict['b'] = n
```

Comment: Thats true but I thought it should be possible to perform this small action in a 1-liner, but thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
if n > _dict['b']:
   _dict['b'] = n
```